# clock() function in C always returns 50 at least

Tags: c

I am not a programmer, but I've recently got interested in coding, started learning C myself, then I started solving questions from ProjectEuler.net with it.

I have been adding these two lines at the end of each source code I am writing:

```
printf ( "The number you are looking for is %d", 0 );
printf ( "\n... and took %d / %d seconds to compute that", clock(), CLOCKS_PER_SEC );
```

... where I replace the zero with the number I need as the answer.

The thing is; no matter how much I optimize my work, the printf never displays less than 50 clocks, even when I use a completely blank source code with no other operations than these two, it still displays 50 clocks. Is it the #include's on top that are spending these 50 clocks, or is it something else?

Some of my filled-up source codes also display 50 clocks; so... I don't know what to deduce here, are some of the things that I had written truly takes 0 milliseconds to get solved?

Comment: subtract 50 and you fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I solved my issue on my own. I recently switched into using Sublime Text to write my source C codes, and made a batch file that compiles an .exe from .c files which uses cl.exe tool of Visual Studio 2012

This has lead me into using the actual .exe's instead of the *Local Windows Debugger* thing on the Visual Studio 2012

And this was when I realized that the +50 clocks happen only with the *Local Windows Debugger*. The code I've just written displays;
- 0~1 clocks when I launch .exe that I generated through Sublime Text + batchCompiler
- 0~1 clocks when I launch the .exe that Visual Studio 2012 generates itself under the `%ProjectDirectory%\Debug\` each time I use the *Local Windows Debugger*
- but 50~51 clocks when I just view the Visual Studio 2012's *Local Windows Debugger*

So... yeah, it's just about the Visual Studio 2012 assisted execution

Answer (score 5):

Your system clock "ticks" every so often (maybe once every 50 milliseconds?) instead of running continuously. So the `clock()` function measures the number of these "ticks" that your process has consumed since it started. This method is not really suitable for measuring time durations that are shorter than one tick.

If you want more precision, you will have to use a *high resolution timer*.

Comment: You might also want to take a look at [this](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/CPU-Time.html) to get a better idea of what's going on here. As the code sample there shows, you should call `clock()` both before and after you do your work and then subtract `start` from `end` to get the elapsed time. That will be 0 in the scenarios you described above.

Comment: @Greg the clock ticks `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` times every second, which is 1000 for my processor, so it rather ticks once every 1 millisecond, at least on my end. Thanks for all that, but I am wondering where that 50 gets spent. As far as I'm aware, the `clock()` displays the amount of ticks starting with the initialization of the program.

Comment: @Ben Yes, I was expecting such a recommendation, but that is somewhat like cheating, since such an implementation would measure the elapsed time from `user-defined-start` to `end`, I would rather like to have the true `start` there; which, as far as I know, the `clock()` function already does itself alone.

Comment: @ThoAppelsin: Your `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` might be 1000, but that doesn't mean that the timer *actually* ticks that frequently. That number just gives you the units of the return value of `clock()`, so you can relate the return value to real world units.

Comment: Don't use `%d` to print a `clock_t` value. The type of `clock_t` is implementation-defined. (On my system, it's a 64-bit signed integer.) The simplest approach is probably to convert to `long` and use `%ld`: `printf("%ld\n", (long)clock());`